# Main .rmd file to fetch data from multiple rmd files

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, flexdashboard

I have three dashboards - dashboard-dec-23.rmd, dashboard-jan-24.rmd, dashboard-feb-24.rmd.

All three dashboards has huge number of charts under multiple tabs and columns.

Now, I want to have all three dashboards under a single rmd file.

I want to have a "month" selection dropdown at the top of the dashboard, where users can select the month.

When Dec'23 is selected, the dashboard dashboard-dec-23.rmd should be rendered and shown. Similarly it should happen for the other two dashboards on selecting the months Jan'24 and Feb'24 respectively.

I already tried knit_child but it merges data from all three dashboards.

I tried selectinput dropdown which overlaps with the tabs and columns of the charts.

The below code didnt work and showed only the frame but not any of the charts. The dashboards work perfectly fine when executed individually.

````yaml
---
title: "Dashboard"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: rows
    vertical_layout: fill
    runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
# Tab 1 {.tabset .tabset-fade}
## December 2023
knitr::knit_child("dashboard-dec-23.rmd")
## January 2024
knitr::knit_child("dashboard-jan-24.rmd")
## February 2024
knitr::knit_child("dashboard-feb-24.rmd")
```
````

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73885724/16730940 - this previous answer may assist?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to split flexdashboard pages into multiple rmd files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73882893/how-to-split-flexdashboard-pages-into-multiple-rmd-files)

Comment: Both the links wont work. In my case, using child option appends all the data together, but I want it to filter based on the selected month.